# Wondering on how to serve different image backgrounds with media queries (especially for retina displays)

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm doing some css code to a website that uses a full cover background and I want to serve it with media queries to a several devices with different resolutions.

I've already figured out how to do that with all the iPhones and iPads doing this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1) { /* for the iPhone 2G/3G/3GS */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width:640px) and (max-device-width:960px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) { /* for the iPhone 4/4S */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width:560px) and (max-device-width:1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) { /* for the iPhone 5 */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1) { /* for the iPad 1/2 and iPad mini */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1536px) and (max-device-width:2048px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) { /* for the iPad 3/4 */ }
```

And for some desktop screens:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1280px), only screen and (min-device-width:1366px), only screen and (min-device-width:1440px) { /* some regular desktop resolutions */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1680px), only screen and (min-device-width:1920px) { /* some larger desktop resolutions, likely hd screens */ }
```

Since the purpose of all this media queries is to satisfy **only** a full cover background using this css rule in each `@media` (with different images, obviously, to reduce server load and display a friendly background considering the specs between devices)...

```
html {
    background:url("image.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;}
```

I have my doubts with doing this for **retina screens** (especially the Macbook Pro Retina, 13inch and 15inch models).

I guess that, using the same logic as above, this should be like this:

```
@media 
only screen and (min-device-width:2560px) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-device-width:2560px) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), 
only screen and (min-device-width:2560px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-device-width:2560px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* for the 13inch model */ }

@media 
only screen and (min-device-width:2880px) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-device-width:2880px) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), 
only screen and (min-device-width:2880px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-device-width:2880px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* for the 15inch model */ }
```

So... I hope this works in this way.

Also, I would like you to give me some advice on improving this. The main idea is that for each display resolution and device, a different image is served, to avoid overloading both the server and the client side (in this case, the browser).

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but maybe these links help?

[CSS Tricks retina display media query](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

[Coder Wall - HD & Retina Display Media Queries](https://coderwall.com/p/jlrerg)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers, but include some detail